# copy only new files to remote host after write is finished

Tags: cron, rsync, scp, nfs

I have a java application which is writing images to a directory.
I want to copy these images from external utility (not from the java application directly).
I can use `scp` and/or `rsync` or other (not sure which one to select) to copy on every, say 5sec interval(mostly using `cron`).

But the main problem here is to know when the write has been finished ?
For example, if the application write is on-going and the schedule ticks for copy, then the image copied will be corrupted.

So what utility should I go for & how can I make sure that the image copied is legit ?

Comment: This really depends on how this "external utility" works. Can you alter the external utility?

Comment: By “external utility” I meant, ‘scp’ / ‘rsync’ etc. But Yes, I can alter the external utility.